# Allow Null And Continue

Tags: json, vb.net, string, null

My JSON

```
{

"name": "username",
   "items": {
    "myitem": {
      "icon": "myitem.jpg",
    "myitem2": {
      "icon": "myitem2.jpg",
}
```

My Code

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://myjson.com/json"), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
        name.Text = If(jResults2("name") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("name").ToString())
        myitem.Text = If(jResults2("items")("myitem")("icon") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("myitem")("icon").ToString())
        myitem2.Text = If(jResults2("items")("myitem2")("icon") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("myitem2")("icon").ToString())



        'Catch ex As Exception
    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()

    End Try
```

im having an issue with my json as sometimes it can look like this

```
{

"name": "username",
   "items": {
    "myitem2": {
      "icon": "myitem2.jpg",
}
```

and when i do the check for null if myitem is not in the json string then name is placed in name.text but myitem2 is not processed or even placed in myitem2.Text

any help to overcome this problem would be great in short if myitem is null i would still like it to continue to process the rest of the items

Comment: That JSON is invalid, what does your RootObject Class for the JSON look like?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in your example is invalid, you can visit this site to validate your JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

I think what you wanted to have looks like the following:

```
{
    "name": "username",
    "items": {
        "myitem": {
            "icon": "myitem.jpg"
        },
        "myitem2": {
            "icon": "myitem2.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

If this is correct then your RootObject for this JSON would look something like so:

```
public class Myitem
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Myitem2
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public Myitem myitem { get; set; }
    public Myitem2 myitem2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry i didn't type it out correctly. however i dont think i understand as what i posted in my code it `name.Text = If(jResults2("name") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("name").ToString())
        myitem.Text = If(jResults2("items")("myitem")("icon") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("myitem")("icon").ToString())
        myitem2.Text = If(jResults2("items")("myitem2")("icon") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("myitem2")("icon").ToString())` how could i set it so when it is going throuhh the json if something is missing it would skip it and continue with the rest